# Relative homology of interlevel set

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

Let us consider a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y,z) = x^3+y^3+z^3 - 5yz$. Can anybody drop a hint how to compute relative homology of interlevel sets with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$: $H_{\bullet}(f^{-1}(-\infty,100),f^{-1}(-\infty,-100),\mathbb{R})$.